# JavaScript variable out side function not retaining the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with the code below, I'm using onclick attribute to call the function below, then checking for which type of data-attr is passed. then assigning it to a local variable outside the function. but some how it saves 1 attr and displays it on alert and show the other one as undefined and then when I click on the other attr it shows it and for the first one says undefined. my js and HTML below.

jQuery code:

```
<script>
var attr1 = null;
var attr2 = null;


function createLink(sportAttr) {

    if($(sportAttr).attr("data-provider-sport-id") != typeof undefined && $(sportAttr).attr("data-provider-sport-id") !== false) {

        attr2 = $(sportAttr).attr("data-provider-sport-id");

        //alert(attr2);
    }

    if($(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id") != typeof undefined && $(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id") !== false) {
        attr1 = $(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id");
        //alert(attr1);
    }

    alert(attr1 + " and second attr is " + attr2);
    //it never reaches the next line because for some reason one of the attrs is always null
    if(attr1 != null && attr2 != null) {

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to create this link")) {

        }

    }

}
</script>
```

HTML code:

```
<i data-provider-sport-id="9" onclick="createLink(this)">Music</i>

<b data-main-sport-id="17" onclick="createLink(this)">Music</b>
```

when I click on the first one it displays "undefined and second attr is 9".

when I click on the second one it displays "17 and second attr is undefined"

any clues?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola - what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This check is incorrect:

```
$(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id") != typeof undefined
```

See, `typeof undefined` is always the *string* `'undefined'` (as typeof always returns a string). This statement will be true unless the data-attribute happens to be the same - i.e. string `'undefined'`.

So your problem is not retention, but the fact that you overwrite the values due to misconfigured `if` statements.

To fix this, use this undefined check *(which you probably tried in the first place)*:

```
typeof $(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id") !== 'undefined'
```

Or just use plain comparison with undefined, without `typeof` *(but this is less robust, so your intuition to use typeof was not bad, per se.)*:

```
$(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id") !== undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking if the attribute is not undefined and value is not false, you can check only the Truthy value as below -

```js
var attr1 = null;
var attr2 = null;


function createLink(sportAttr) {

    if($(sportAttr).attr("data-provider-sport-id")) {

        attr2 = $(sportAttr).attr("data-provider-sport-id");

        //alert(attr2);
    }

    if($(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id")) {
        attr1 = $(sportAttr).attr("data-main-sport-id");
        //alert(attr1);
    }

    alert(attr1 + " and second attr is " + attr2);
    //it never reaches the next line because for some reason one of the attrs is always null
    if(attr1 != null && attr2 != null) {

        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to create this link")) {

        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah i guess thats another way to go on about it, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First I recommend to you avoid to set the `onclick` on your html, it's not a good practice. Also I have improved your code, take a look below:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myAction').on('click', function(){
        createLink($(this).data('id'))
    });

});

function createLink(sportAttr) {
    if(typeof sportAttr !== 'undefined') {
        alert(sportAttr);
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<i class="myAction" data-id="9" data-provider-sport-id="9">Music</i>

<b class="myAction" data-id="17" data-main-sport-id="17">Music</b>
```

Basically the idea is make a generic function and try to reduce the code and make it more clean, also you were not checking properly the `undefined`.

```
if(typeof sportAttr !== 'undefined') {
        alert(sportAttr);
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/co702orz/3/)

I hope it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `typeof` operator,  `typeof undefined` is `"undefined"`.